# Equal Suprema of Two functions on a Closed Interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f,g$ be continuous non-negative functions on the interval $[0,1]$ and let $\sup{f}=\sup{g}$ on $[0,1]$.  Show that there exists a $t\in[0,1]$ such that $f(t)^2+5f(t)=g(t)^2+5g(t)$

I'm not sure how to procede.  If the supremums are equal, this does not mean necessarily mean these maximums occur for the same $t$.  For example, if $f=\cos{\pi x}, g=\sin{\pi x}, \sup{f}=\sup{g}=1$.  I'm not sure how the nonnegative fact comes into play either.  My idea is that I need to find a point of intersection of $f$ and $g$, and since at that value of $t$ they are equal, then at tthat point you can also say that $f^2+5f=g^2+5g$.  I am just not sure how to procede though.

Comment: Can you show that there is a $t\in [0,1]$ such that $f(t) = g(t)$?

Comment: I was thinking to consider a function $h(t)=f(t)-g(t)$ and using the IVT (int. value)?

Comment: Good. Now all that remains is to find points $a,b$ such that $h(a) \leqslant 0 \leqslant h(b)$.

Comment: Unless the supremums are equal at a particular $t$, then let $f(a)=\sup{f}$?  then I'm thinking $f(a)>g(a)$ and then play the same game with $g(b)=\sup{g}$?

Comment: I got it from here.  I thought this was the case as I talked it out to myself.  Thank you for your help @DanielFischer